# React Flux: How to trigger a one-time initial load after authenticating

Tags: authentication, reactjs, initialization, bootstrapping, reactjs-flux

**I'm using a higher-order wrapper component** as a root that accomplishes 2 things:

1. Verify auth (redirect to login or home)
2. Do the initial load to store once the auth is complete.

I'm finding it hard to do those 2 things in this one wrapper class because **I can't find a way to do a one-time initial load trigger if the user is not authenticated(has no existing session)**

So for example I trigger a load when there is a session with a callback:

```
componentWillMount: function() {
    LoginStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
    var authData = AuthAPIUtils.checkForSession();
    if(authData !== null)  {
       WebAPIUtils.loadStores(this.onBootstrapComplete);
    }
},
```

**"this.onBootstrapComplete"** is a callback that will change the wrapper state

```
onBootstrapComplete: function() {
    console.log("5-the final callback was made - onBootstrapComplete");
    //localStorage.setItem( 'gvLoggedIn', true ); This is set true in home
    this.setState({
        bootstrapComplete: true,
    });
  },
```

**"this.state.bootstrapComplete"** is passed down the child components to switch from a loading spinner to rendering the components

```
render: function(){
    if(this.state.loggedIn) {
        var childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children,function(child) { 
        return React.cloneElement(child,{bootstrapComplete : this.state.bootstrapComplete}) 
        },this);

        return (
            <div className="wrapper-container">
                {childrenWithProps} 
            </div>
        )
    }
    else {
        return ( 
            <div className="wrapper-container">
                <Login />
            </div>
        ) 
     }
```

But when there isn't a session this callback solution for a one-time trigger breaks down.

**I looked hard for a solution and the best I've come up with is:**

1. The wrapper can only listen to a "LoginStore" which should only trigger once when there is a login and logout and then use _onChange to check for a log in and trigger the loading then.
2. Create a handler in the wrapper class and pass it down to the Login class as a callback.

Maybe one of those solutions is just fine(let me know if so) but I wanted to make sure I'm not doing something fundamentally poor to bootstrap my app.

Answer (score 1):

For me it looks like the good approach. Just one point maybe, AuthAPIUtils should be an action file (but maybe it is already) and manage the dispatching. Reading at your code I think you're already using it this way. Otherwise I think your approach

*1.The wrapper can only listen to a "LoginStore" which should only trigger once when there is a login and logout and then use _onChange to check for a log in and trigger the loading then.
2.Create a handler in the wrapper class and pass it down to the Login class as a callback.*

is good